# Selecting an object by it's id using django with heroku postgresql

Tags: sqlite, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've got an app running on Heroku with Django, the local DB I use SQLite, but on Heroku the app uses PostgreSQL.

I'm having a problem and I've no idea why is happening. Let me explain myself:

I select an object from DB by it's id, locally it works perfectly, but on Heroku, the result is that it cannot find the object.

I know that the id of the object is correct, and the way I'm trying to select the object is the same as the way I did dozens of times.

Here's the code that haves the issue:

```
data = simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)
if 'id' and 'type' in data:
  ide=data['id']
  type=data['type']
  if type == 'selection':
    if ObjSel.objects.filter(id=ide).exists():
      ej = ObjSel.objects.get(id=ide)
      [....]
    else:
      return HttpResponse(
          simplejson.dumps({'result': 'fail', 'message': 'Object not found'}), 
          mimetype='application/json'
      )
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: the mysql is there because in local the DB is mysql, not postgresql

Comment: Thanks for fixing all that up; I've removed the now irrelevant comments and reversed my downvote. Now ... can you show the actual SQL query that Django runs? (You might need to enable extra logging/tracing in Django). It's hard to say what could be going on without that. You can edit your question to add the info.